# Searching for a good PHP based Web Counter

Tags: php, plugins, counter

I am running a php based web application and within that application I am using [bbclone](http://www.bbclone.de) to count visitors and site activity.
Unfortunately it doesn't work that nice as expected because bbclone counts a lot of robots and therefor my statistic is not that accurate as it should be.

So do you know any good php based web application counter?
It would be nice to have the following overviews in it:

- user agents
- timeline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics)? They have an API that you can use to present the data to the user any way you choose. (I have no experience with the API though, but I'm going to do something with it soon, probably).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Just configured Google Analytics (which was pretty easy). Works fine!

Answer (score 4):

Try [Piwik](http://piwik.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I came a cross trendcounter, never tested!

http://www.trendcounter.com/

Answer (score 0):

if you are using bbclone, try iPhone version (if you have iPhone) :)) ... it's called iBBClone and the website is here: http://www.ibbclone.com/